# Android Widget Configuration Open Activity

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, android-appwidget

I want to create a widget for an app and have already written `widget provider` and `configuration` classes. I just have one image in widget layout and when it is clicked, I want it to open `MyActivity` Activity class. On configuration layout there is one red image, when I click that image, widget image gets changed. The **Problem** is when I click the widget, it does not open `MyActivity`.

Where should I put `views.setOnClickPendingIntent`? Into `appWidgetProvider` ? Into `appWidgetConfiguration`? Into both?

**Question 2** is: Do I have to put this code into `MyActivity` in order to open it with widget click? : `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME));`

Here is what I have:

**appwidget.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageWidget" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**appWidgetProvider.java**

```
public class OffAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;               
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageWidget, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
```

**appWidgetConfiguration.java**

```
public class AppWidgetConfiguration extends Activity{
    private int mAppWidgetId;
    private ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_appwidget_configuration);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageWidgetRed);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context= AppWidgetConfiguration.this;
                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.appwidget);
                views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageWidget,R.mipmap.widgetred);                        

                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);

                Intent resultValue = new Intent();
                resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
                finish();
            }
        });   

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** It turns out that i have to put `views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageWidget, pendingIntent);` to both `appWidgetProvider` and `appWidgetConfiguration` before the line `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);`. Below is what i have written for click listener:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.appwidget);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageWidget, pendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);
```

**2)** I can open my activity which has xml layout without putting this code in target activity: `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME))`. But `MyActivity.java` does not have xml layout and i had to put this code (into `Oncreate`) in order to open it with widget click. Second option is instead of putting this in target activity, write `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);` when opening that activity as above.